# Cannot find symbol variable i in for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop

When I compile I get the error

> cannot find symbol - variable i

```
static void plusMinus(int[] arr) {
   int pos = 0, neg = 0, zero = 0;
   int arrlength = arr.length;

   for(i = 0; i < arrlength; i++){

       if(arr[i] > 1){
           pos += 1;
       } else if(arr[i] < 0){
           neg += 1;
       } else if(arr[i] == 0){
           zero += 1;
       }
       }

    double posfrac = pos/arr.length, negfrac = neg/arr.length, zerofrac = 
    zero/arr.length;

    System.out.println(posfrac);
    System.out.println(negfrac);
    System.out.println(zerofrac);
}
```

I made sure my curly brackets properly defined my scope but I still get the same error. There is more code after this but not errors in that part.

Comment: `i` has never been declared. Change your loop to `for(int i = 0; i < arrlength; i++)`

Comment: Andronicus's answer fully answers your question. I would recommend marking their suggestion as correct to close this post.

Comment: Thankyou, that worked

Comment: I have to wait 15 mins after the post to accept an answer apparently

Comment: follow the common practices, assign data type to variable i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `i` first in the `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrlength; i++)
   ^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you never declared i

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
```